# canActivate issue

Tags: angular6

I am a beginner to angular 6. I have some doubts regarding canActivate to allow users to access a URL for authorized users:-

Code below:-

app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from 'src/app/app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from 'src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/app/guards/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: AppComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { TokenvalidityService } from '../services/tokenvalidity.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router, private _tokenvalidityService: TokenvalidityService) { }

    public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        console.log("Auth guard "+localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
        console.log(this._tokenvalidityService.checkTokenExpired());

        if (!this._tokenvalidityService.checkTokenExpired()) {
            console.log("Inside Auth guard if");
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/home'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now if try to hit the url(http://localhost:4200/dashboard) for authenticated users, it is redirecting to home page(http://localhost:4200). But i could see the logged in user details in local storage.

Could you please help me on this. Iam not able to track why this redirection not working.

package.json file:-

```
{
  "name": "angular-test-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 6.0.8.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the output of the logs. Have you tried debugging this bit `this._tokenvalidityService.checkTokenExpired()`.